# Powershell Script to fetch Websites current connections Hosted in IIS

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fetch the details of current connection for website hosted in IIS. I tried bit of coding and generated below snippet. With below code I am getting the data successfully but I want to see
server name ,
current connection and site name only in the HTML result. As of now what I am getting is below:-

> \servername1\web service(sitename)\current connections : 59
>
> \servername2\web service(sitename)\current connections : 81.

This is quite hard for other people to read out the report correctly. Can someone help me here to get the better HTML report consisting of sitename/servername/current connections/timestamp. Below is code snippet

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:peachpuff;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"
import-module webadministration
$sitename = dir IIS:\Sites | Select Name
 
function get-CurrentConnection($Site) {

Get-Counter "web service($Site)\current connections" -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\server1.txt)
} 
 
 
 
 $CurrentConnection = @()
foreach ($Site in $SiteName) 
    {
       #Write-Host $Site
       $CC = get-CurrentConnection -Site $Site.name |Select Readings,Timestamp 
        $CurrentConnection += $cc
    }
 
 
    $CurrentConnection | ConvertTo-Html -head $a |out-file C:\report.htm
    Invoke-Expression  "C:\report.htm"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what fields are in your object, but you should be able to adapt this to your code to get the desired output.

Create the `[pscustomobject]` inside your loop accordingly and add to your `$CurrentConnection` array.

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:peachpuff;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 0px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

$CurrentConnection = @()

$data = [pscustomobject]@{
"site" = "sitename1"
"server" = "servername1"
"connections" = "123"
"date" = (Get-Date)
}
$CurrentConnection += $data

$data = [pscustomobject]@{
"site" = "sitename2"
"server" = "servername2"
"connections" = "456"
"date" = (Get-Date)
}
$CurrentConnection += $data


$CurrentConnection | ConvertTo-Html -Head $a | Out-File d:\test\foo.htm

Invoke-Item d:\test\foo.htm
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but getting same results in the HTML report that i posted earlier. Also since i have to run the script among large number of servers so i wont be able to create custom object like above. Basically what i am looking in HTML report is in first column i get server name then 2nd column need site name,3rd need current connection from perfmon counter webservice/surrent connection and last is timestamp.